# Все говорят что мд5 не декодировать ,имея фун.хеширования как ее запустить в обратном порядке?

Tags: хеширование

//Функция хеширования мд5

```
var MD5=function(d){d=unescape(encodeURIComponent(d));result=M(V(Y(X(d),8*d.length)));return result.toLowerCase()};function M(d){for(var _,m="0123456789ABCDEF",f="",r=0;r<d.length;r++)_=d.charCodeAt(r),f+=m.charAt(_>>>4&15)+m.charAt(15&_);return f}function X(d){for(var _=Array(d.length>>2),m=0;m<_.length;m++)_[m]=0;for(m=0;m<8*d.length;m+=8)_[m>>5]|=(255&d.charCodeAt(m/8))<<m%32;return _}function V(d){for(var _="",m=0;m<32*d.length;m+=8)_+=String.fromCharCode(d[m>>5]>>>m%32&255);return _}function Y(d,_){d[_>>5]|=128<<_%32,d[14+(_+64>>>9<<4)]=_;for(var m=1732584193,f=-271733879,r=-1732584194,i=271733878,n=0;n<d.length;n+=16){var h=m,t=f,g=r,e=i;f=md5_ii(f=md5_ii(f=md5_ii(f=md5_ii(f=md5_hh(f=md5_hh(f=md5_hh(f=md5_hh(f=md5_gg(f=md5_gg(f=md5_gg(f=md5_gg(f=md5_ff(f=md5_ff(f=md5_ff(f=md5_ff(f,r=md5_ff(r,i=md5_ff(i,m=md5_ff(m,f,r,i,d[n+0],7,-680876936),f,r,d[n+1],12,-389564586),m,f,d[n+2],17,606105819),i,m,d[n+3],22,-1044525330),r=md5_ff(r,i=md5_ff(i,m=md5_ff(m,f,r,i,d[n+4],7,-176418897),f,r,d[n+5],12,1200080426),m,f,d[n+6],17,-1473231341),i,m,d[n+7],22,-45705983),r=md5_ff(r,i=md5_ff(i,m=md5_ff(m,f,r,i,d[n+8],7,1770035416),f,r,d[n+9],12,-1958414417),m,f,d[n+10],17,-42063),i,m,d[n+11],22,-1990404162),r=md5_ff(r,i=md5_ff(i,m=md5_ff(m,f,r,i,d[n+12],7,1804603682),f,r,d[n+13],12,-40341101),m,f,d[n+14],17,-1502002290),i,m,d[n+15],22,1236535329),r=md5_gg(r,i=md5_gg(i,m=md5_gg(m,f,r,i,d[n+1],5,-165796510),f,r,d[n+6],9,-1069501632),m,f,d[n+11],14,643717713),i,m,d[n+0],20,-373897302),r=md5_gg(r,i=md5_gg(i,m=md5_gg(m,f,r,i,d[n+5],5,-701558691),f,r,d[n+10],9,38016083),m,f,d[n+15],14,-660478335),i,m,d[n+4],20,-405537848),r=md5_gg(r,i=md5_gg(i,m=md5_gg(m,f,r,i,d[n+9],5,568446438),f,r,d[n+14],9,-1019803690),m,f,d[n+3],14,-187363961),i,m,d[n+8],20,1163531501),r=md5_gg(r,i=md5_gg(i,m=md5_gg(m,f,r,i,d[n+13],5,-1444681467),f,r,d[n+2],9,-51403784),m,f,d[n+7],14,1735328473),i,m,d[n+12],20,-1926607734),r=md5_hh(r,i=md5_hh(i,m=md5_hh(m,f,r,i,d[n+5],4,-378558),f,r,d[n+8],11,-2022574463),m,f,d[n+11],16,1839030562),i,m,d[n+14],23,-35309556),r=md5_hh(r,i=md5_hh(i,m=md5_hh(m,f,r,i,d[n+1],4,-1530992060),f,r,d[n+4],11,1272893353),m,f,d[n+7],16,-155497632),i,m,d[n+10],23,-1094730640),r=md5_hh(r,i=md5_hh(i,m=md5_hh(m,f,r,i,d[n+13],4,681279174),f,r,d[n+0],11,-358537222),m,f,d[n+3],16,-722521979),i,m,d[n+6],23,76029189),r=md5_hh(r,i=md5_hh(i,m=md5_hh(m,f,r,i,d[n+9],4,-640364487),f,r,d[n+12],11,-421815835),m,f,d[n+15],16,530742520),i,m,d[n+2],23,-995338651),r=md5_ii(r,i=md5_ii(i,m=md5_ii(m,f,r,i,d[n+0],6,-198630844),f,r,d[n+7],10,1126891415),m,f,d[n+14],15,-1416354905),i,m,d[n+5],21,-57434055),r=md5_ii(r,i=md5_ii(i,m=md5_ii(m,f,r,i,d[n+12],6,1700485571),f,r,d[n+3],10,-1894986606),m,f,d[n+10],15,-1051523),i,m,d[n+1],21,-2054922799),r=md5_ii(r,i=md5_ii(i,m=md5_ii(m,f,r,i,d[n+8],6,1873313359),f,r,d[n+15],10,-30611744),m,f,d[n+6],15,-1560198380),i,m,d[n+13],21,1309151649),r=md5_ii(r,i=md5_ii(i,m=md5_ii(m,f,r,i,d[n+4],6,-145523070),f,r,d[n+11],10,-1120210379),m,f,d[n+2],15,718787259),i,m,d[n+9],21,-343485551),m=safe_add(m,h),f=safe_add(f,t),r=safe_add(r,g),i=safe_add(i,e)}return Array(m,f,r,i)}function md5_cmn(d,_,m,f,r,i){return safe_add(bit_rol(safe_add(safe_add(_,d),safe_add(f,i)),r),m)}function md5_ff(d,_,m,f,r,i,n){return md5_cmn(_&m|~_&f,d,_,r,i,n)}function md5_gg(d,_,m,f,r,i,n){return md5_cmn(_&f|m&~f,d,_,r,i,n)}function md5_hh(d,_,m,f,r,i,n){return md5_cmn(_^m^f,d,_,r,i,n)}function md5_ii(d,_,m,f,r,i,n){return md5_cmn(m^(_|~f),d,_,r,i,n)}function safe_add(d,_){var m=(65535&d)+(65535&_);return(d>>16)+(_>>16)+(m>>16)<<16|65535&m}function bit_rol(d,_){return d<<_|d>>>32-_}


var result=MD5('vova');
console.log(result);
```

/*Возможно ли функцию запустить задом на перед и размотать клубок хеша до входного значения и если нет то почему*/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287704/how-to-reverse-md5-to-get-the-original-string

Comment: Обратная функция `md5 ^ -1` имеет бесконечно много значений. А правильный путь найти как в лабиринте. Налево пойдёшь, и можешь не возвращаться. Вдруг там правильный путь?

Answer (score 1):

> и если нет то почему/

потому что md5 занимает 16 байт, а формируется из данных **ЛЮБОГО** размера

это значит, что, к примеру, всего возможно 256^16 = 34000000000000000000000000000000000000 вариант md5, а если взять буфер в 100 байт, то возможно уже 256^100 вариантов, а значит будут возможны коллизии (например взять какой-нибудь crc8, который дает лишь 256 возможных значений, захэшируйте им 1000 слов и в среднем на каждый хэш у вас придется по 4 слова - и куда спрашивается вы раскручивать crc8 будете?)

так что раскрутить назад не получится

**однако** можно составить 2 буфера так, чтобы их md5 были одинаковыми (была работа чешских или польских математиков, уже не помню, которые показали как это делается практически)

Обратная раскрутка md5 возможна только в одном случае - если кол-во первоначальных вариантов было меньше (гораздо меньше) вариантов md5 (см. выше)

Например, если телефонные номера вида (xxx)xxx-xx-xx хэшировать с помощью md5, то возможно сделать даже не обратную раскрутку, а составить таблицу соответствий или подобрать брутфорсом - поскольку требуется вычислить всего лишь 10^10 вариантов номеров (на самом деле меньше, около 10^9 из-за исключения 0 в начале номера)

На этом принципе основаны взломы паролей (например взять миллион самых популярных паролей, вычислить для них md5 и потом просто сравнивать с исследуемой md5)

- есть радужные таблицы, позволяющие вычислять куски паролей

правда против этого всегда есть соль :) и есть ее не знать, то подобрать даже 1 байтовые пароли будет невозможно

соль - это мусорные символы, которые добавляются в пароль перед его хэшированием (например 256 байт в начале или в конце, а лучше конечно распределённых по паролю более хитрым способом)

Comment: а интересно, пробовал ли кто то доказать, что для любого md5 хеша всегда есть хотя бы два варианта. Ок, хотя бы один:) я понимаю, закон больших чисел и все такое, но все же

Comment: @KoVadim, вроде да - к хэшам предъявляется требование о РАВНОМЕРНОСТИ распределения значений, т.е. если вы вычислите очень много буферов - значительно больше, чем возможных вариантов хэшей, то кол-во буферов на 1 хэш должно быть одинаковым (плюс-минус), хотя доказать равномерность гораздо сложнее, а вот заполненность - гораздо легче - можно провести обратную раскрутку md5, просто там на каждом этапе будет появляться неоднозначность - типа выбрать ветку А или ветку Б в зависимости от данных, но выбор есть всегда и поэтому можно показать, что от любой MD5 можно через эти ветки провести путь

Comment: я знаю это. Но я придирчивый:) я хочу строгое доказательство:) Было бы приятно, если какой то хеш было бы невозможно получить. тогда был бы такой себе nullptr хеш

Comment: По идее, если данные не абстрактные, то можно ограничить выборку вариантов того, из чего считается md5, но в целом занятие безнадёжное, да )

Comment: я понял, такого никто не пытался доказать.

Comment: @CrazyElf, конечно можно, но например у нас есть роман "Война и Мир" - ограничение - точный размер кол-ва символов, сам набор символов, набор слов (чтобы ПРВПЫГВЫФшш не получалось), но вот я очень сомневаюсь, что с 1 md5 все равно при таких довольно таки жестких ограничениях можно будет получить только одну войну и мир, а не еще какие-то тексты, содержащие только буквы/цифры и существующие слова.

Comment: @KoVadim, что именно? если вы про то, что каждому значению хэша соответствуют свои данные - то конечно это доказано, когда доказывалась равномерность распределения по значениям хэшей, если вы про вариант CrazyElf, то я такие доказательства не встречал, но есть доказательства уязвимости md5 как алгоритма (т.е. возможность зная md5 получить ХОТЯ БЫ какой буфер, из которого можно этот md5 получить)

Comment: @Zhihar Ну, если припахать анализ на то, что получаются слова из человеческого словаря в основном... В вообще интересная тема, надо попробовать её покопать )

Comment: @CrazyElf, можно сделать оценку с точностью до нескольких порядков - т.е. взять буфер размером Z и прикинуть сколько в нем может быть комбинаций слов (для мегабайтного файла там наверное 10^1000+ уже будет), потом прикинуть сколько срежется на правильной форме предложений (даже если порядков 100) и сравнить с 10^38 - вот что-то мне кажется, что все равно будет гораздо больше возможных вариантов, а значит есть реальные шансы сложить разные тексты для 1 md5

Comment: то, что для какого то хеша может быть 10 и более вариантов начального буфера - это интересно, но гораздо интереснее, есть ли такие хеши, что бы их нельзя было получить. И тут Ваше обяснения пасует.

Comment: @Zhihar Что-то я попробовал просто перестановки делать, так просто комбинации из 2-х английских слов оно собирается 7 часов перебирать ((  А если с подсчётом md5, то все 30 часов. Безнадёжное дело короче. Очень много комбинаций при словаре в 200 000 английских слов. Если только взять какой-то суперкороткий словарь.

Comment: @KoVadim, потому что я объяснял на пальцах :) если не ограничивать начальные параметры A,B,C,D при вычислении MD5, то вообще нет ограничений на существование md5 значений, которым нет соответствующего буфера - вы просто делаете 1!!! операцию, обратную от вычисления в цикле значений A.B.C.D (т.е. считаем, что цикл был только 1) и на выходе вы получаете буфер!!! Все. Доказано. Сложнее показать, что такими циклами можно прийти к первоначальным ненулевым заданным A,B,C,D. Но я тут уже не помогу :) надо всякие методы Ван Сяоюня и Юй Хунбо смотреть и им подобные :)

Comment: @CrazyElf, а суперкороткий словарь не поможет, потому что для нужного эффекта тогда кол-во слов должно быть очень большим и опять же очень долго будет считаться. По идее легко доказать, что имея только 2 слова, например для удобства возьмем 2 слова одинаковой длины "кот" и "кит" мы 1) из-за ограниченности кол-ва вариантов значений md5 получим одинаковые md5 для 2 текстов, содержащих только 1 слово, но в разном кол-ве 2) содержащие разные слова, но одинаковое кол-во этих слов (например условно "кит кот" и "кот кит" будут иметь одинаковые md5)

Comment: @CrazyElf, для словаря из одного слова (но повторенного много раз) самый неудобный случай будет требовать размер текста в N * 10^38 букв (где N - размер слова)

Comment: @Zhihar если бы все так было просто, то теорему Ферма тоже в один коммент вместили бы.

Comment: @KoVadim, ну если предположить, что abc-гипотеза верна, то Великую теорему Ферма я и в 1 комментарии смогу доказать :))))